# Can I keep my code loosely coupled with public-facing enums?

Tags: c#, design, interfaces, enum

I have some `enum`s in a concrete API/library that will be publicly used by application projects. My problem here, is that I cannot write an interface to these `enum`s (that I know of). I should have thought of this before starting the project, but I did not. What really complicates this is that some of the methods accept/return the `enum`s as arguments/parameters.

**Question**

Is there any way to keep my code loosely coupled, while still keeping the `enum`s publicly facing the application?

Would it be acceptable to just put the `enum`s into the `interface` library (as opposed to the concrete's/implementation's library)?

Comment: The enums are already part of the API.  What exactly would you be abstracting with an interface?  Nothing about the customer-facing API changes if you add a number to the enum.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes it would, I have an enum containing a bunch of relay-numbers that can be closed/opened. If I add another relay-number to the enum, then that's one more relay the customer can close/open. Do you see what I am asking now?

Comment: @RobertHarvey And the thing is, I need to define the customer API objects through an interface because the implementation may change. As an electrical-engineer, in my particular case I am dealing with pieces of equipment

Comment: @RobertHarvey But I do see what you are saying, in it's current state.... No, adding a number to the enum would not affect the customer API in any way whatsoever but only because enums cannot be abstracted to an interface (that I know of).

Comment: How generic is your API? In my experience, API's that involve instrumentation usually require Key/Value pairs, because you cannot anticipate ahead of time what outputs a sensor or piece of equipment provides ahead of time.  You can represent that kind of data with an arbitrary JSON or XML definition, but changing a DTO in C# is a breaking change, or at least one that requires programmer intervention.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You're spot on, there are always key/value pairs. What we do usually involves some command and an associated response (aside from when our devices are doing asynchronous data communications).

Comment: @RobertHarvey But on an additional note, XML/JSON may not be the answer because there are a limited number of commands that a device will actually support. Then, the implementation of each command/response pair will be very distinct for each possible pair, so programmer intervention would be required whenever a new pair would be added anyways.